# DropDownList.Optgroup.MVC Pass Selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dll, drop-down-menu

I'm using a DDL **DropDownList.Optgroup.MVC** (Helper class for <optgroup> tag in MVC)

My code is as follows:

```
MvcApplication1.Models.Database1Context db = new MvcApplication1.Models.Database1Context();
    var data = db.locations.ToList().Select(t => new GroupedSelectListItem
    {
        GroupKey = t.location_group_id.ToString(),
        GroupName = t.location_group.name,
        Text = t.name,
        Value = t.id.ToString()
    });
```

I'm not getting how to pass the selected value? (i.e. Selected location in this case)

Any idea about how to handle this while Using Database Context as above?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var data = db.locations.ToList().Select(t => new GroupedSelectListItem
        {
            GroupKey = t.location_group_id.ToString(),
            GroupName = t.location_group.name,
            Text = t.name,
            Value = t.id.ToString(),
            Selected= t.Id == 1;//specify condition you want.
        });
```